# Are there dual port PCIe x1 gigabit NICs available?

Tags: vmware-esxi, pci-express

Are there dual port PCIe x1 gigabit NICs available?

I only know of ones that require a x4 slot, but if PCIe v2 doubles the bandwidth per lane, and PCIe v3 quadruples it, there ought to be dual port PCIe v2/3 NICs that only require a x1 slot, surely?

I've only got one x1 PCIe v2 slot available on a machine which ideally needs another two network ports.

To add to the complication, it needs to be compatible with VMware ESXi, so an Intel chipset is desirable.

Comment: I couldn't find one from shops here in Finland. All I could find are for x4, same what you knew already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this ?
http://www.ebuyer.com/product/229050?utm_source=google&utm_medium=products

Comment: The problem is that the it has a Realtek chipset which usually does not work with VMware ESXi, and I have not been able to find out if this particular one does - probably not.  The specs do not mention which revision of PCI Express it requires http://us.startech.com/product/ST1000SPEXDP-Dual-Port-PCI-Express-Gigabit-Ethernet-NIC-Network-Adapter-Card.  I'll look for more information on it, and at least I know that they do exist. Thanks.

Comment: under spec of the link i posted: Interface (Bus) Type: PCI Express x1    -- ive used them for a rhel5 machine, no vmware though,

Comment: @Sirex: I meant if it uses PCIe v1, v2, etc.  PCIe v1 x1 would get saturated by two gigabit ports running at full duplex.  ESXi is actually based on Red Hat, but the HCL is quite restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

You want an Intel [Pro/1000 PT](http://www.intel.com/products/server/adapters/pro1000pt-dualport/pro1000pt-dualport-overview.htm) adapter, [HERE](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=io&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=50&key=&release%5B%5D=148&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=46&manufacturer%5B%5D=-1&vid=&did=&svid=&ssid=&rorre=0)'s it's certification with ESXi 4.1u1.

Comment: That card still requires an x4 slot.